# How to access Maya Bonus Tools 2012 in Maya 2014

Tags: geometry, tools, maya

I have been trying to use the paint geometry tool for Maya 2014 but it isnt showing up. I downloaded Bonus Tools 2012 and installed it. Where can I find this tool in Maya 2014?

Comment: Are you sure the 2012 version is even compatible? Why not use the 2014 version of the bonus tools?

Comment: i have tried downloading Bonus Tools 2014 but when i went into the plugin-manager, there was no geometry paint tool. I dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: I tried downloading Maya Bonus Tools for 2014 but it didnt seem to come with the paint geometry tool

Answer (score 1):

In Maya 2014 you go to Modify -> Paint Scripts Tool [Options] -> Setup. Enter "geometryPaint" under 'Tool setup cmd:' and there you have it!

Answer (score 0):

paint geometry tool for higher Maya versions, e.g. 2017:
run the script inside the mel console(you can drag and drop the script line from the mel console to a shelf, too) to get the legacy paint geometry tool (from maya bonus tools 2012):

ScriptPaintTool; artUserPaintCtx -e -tsc "geometryPaint" `currentCtx`;